# How can I insert ř in text?

Tags: text-object

I am creating short educative animation in Czech language. And I ran in the big trouble with title scene. **In the scene I need insert text with character "ř" and blender refuses insert "ř" without error message** I doesn't find help in the manual of blender. (I am using **blender 2.92**)

Comment: Which font are you using? The font must contain Czech characters in the first place, before you can use them in Blender.

Comment: it works with Cambria: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Yvy.png

Answer (score 3):

You need a font that includes those special characters like  <kbd>ě</kbd> <kbd>š</kbd> <kbd>č</kbd> <kbd>ř</kbd> <kbd>ž</kbd> <kbd>ň</kbd>.
The default Blender font doesn't.

High-quality commercial fonts (Helvetica Neue, Futura, Bodoni) usually include these  characters.
You can also use [Google Fonts library](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=%C4%9B%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%99%C5%BE%C5%88&preview.text_type=custom&preview.size=75) to find free fonts with extended character support.

[image]

[image]